# Two windows in separate thread becoming active together

Tags: c++, mfc

I have two modal dialogs and each dialog has one edit box. I am creating these dialog boxes in two separate threads. But sometimes when these dialog boxes become visible, both edit boxes are showing a blinking cursor and both windows are appearing active - which means that the title bars of both windows are appearing blue. I am not able to work out why this behaviour is being shown by the dialogs.

Can anyone help me in pointing out where I might be wrong??

Comment: Yes both dialogs are modal dialogs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate threads are separately schedulable, so unless the two threads coordinate their activity, it would be possible for both to be active at one time - as you describe - unless there is something in MFC that ensures that only one modal dialog can be active at a time.  Make sure the threads coordinate things so that only one of the dialogs is active at any given time.

Ah, the joys of multiple cores...